# Expand and collapse titles in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to collapse or expand titles in Word with VBA?

[image: Image explaining what I want to do]

I would greatly appreciate your time and support with this problem please.

Being able to automate the expansion or contraction of headings in Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collapses all the headings in the active document.

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.CollapseAllHeadings 

' ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.ExpandAllHeadings
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [View.CollapseAllHeadings method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.view.collapseallheadings?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [View.ExpandAllHeadings method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.view.expandallheadings?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you helped me